# Accessing SharePoint files through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to be able to list my SharePoint files using a token obtained from AAD app. So far I'm not getting any authorisation errors - [so not like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878180/trying-to-search-sharepoint-files-using-microsoft-graph-api) and I'm able to make the call correctly, however I'm seeing different results for the same account through Microsoft's Graph Explorer and what I have.
I can see and list my files / drives in the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) using the url:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mytenant.sharepoint.com/drive/root/children
```

This however doesn't work with the AAD app that I have which I've requested the following accesses from Microsoft Graph API

[image]

I'm guessing either the graph tool is enabled with some features that the rest of us doesn't have, or I'm requesting the wrong set of permissions.
Any ideas to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share the differences between the Graph Explorer and your API calls. You don't really leave us with much to work off of.

Comment: Sure - the Graph API Explorer would actually list the files, but my own access with my AAD token was showing up no files. I have solved this problem now, it looks like you needed to disable and re-enable the aad app for the account if you were changing permissions. I was expecting to get the prompt again but I didn't get prompted.

Comment: Just an FYI, Graph Explorer uses the exact same endpoints and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding permission(s) to your application, users will have to consent even if they’ve already done so previously.

And you doesn't need to disable and re-enable the aad app for the account if you were changing permissions. As an administrator, you can consent to an application's delegated permissions on behalf of all the users in your tenant. The easiest way you can do this from the Azure portal from your application page. From the `Settings` blade for your application, click `Required Permissions` and click on the `Grant Permissions` button.

Comment: For clarification, this was exactly what I was hoping to happen. It didn't. I didn't get a consent page again even if I was changing the permissions. I had to remove and re-activate the app for that account and only then with the new permissions I was able to see the list of files.

Comment: try add `prompt=admin_consent` to your login request for admin consent ,and `prompt=consent` for user consent .